# VB using me.close before opening new form

Tags: vb.net

Hi Guys i'm new to Visual Basic Coding, and i can't seem to get where's my mistake on my coding, i'm trying to create a button that opens a new form while closing the current form.

i have two forms, form 1 is MainForm, form 2 is SearchForm

Whenever i use this code:

```
Private Sub SearchMButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchMButton.Click    
        MainForm.Close()
        SearchForm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

it will generate an error and says i need to replace MainForm.Close() into Me.Close()
When i Use this

```
Private Sub SearchMButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchMButton.Click    
        Me.Close()
        SearchForm.Show()    
    End Sub
End Class
```

It closes both Forms and it doesn't leave any Form Open. Kindly direct me to the proper path, thanks in advance.

Comment: Project + Properties, change Shutdown mode to "When last form closes".  Spend another couple of hours looking around, this is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 if something isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Hide` the form rather than closing it.  Since it's your main form, when it closes, the application exits.

Comment: Thanks i thought it was something like that, based from observation. Sorry i'm new to visual basic.net, how do you distinguish a main form and a sub form? cause when i look at their file name they are both name Form and both .vb @Douglas Barbin? Thanks

Comment: @user3476579: Psst... You can give the form any name you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard UI guidelines are to leave the main form open, and open search form on top of that. If you need to block the main form, while search criteria are selected, use `.ShowDialog`, instead of just `.Show`.

.NET WinForms programming pattern kind of implies that you never close your main form. If you deviate from this approach, you are guaranteed to encounter all sorts of layout and display issues. So please don't. You can `.Hide` the main form, if it needs to go to system tray or run in background.